# jQuery change the width of input search box

Tags: jquery, input, width, selector, bind

I would like to change the width of input search box as soon as the cursor was placed in the input box.

However once the user click on any of the body element which is not input box, I would like the width go back to its original length.
However it seems that the program also change the width back to its original length even when the cursor was placed in the search box. How do I select body element which is not input box.

```
<form class="search" action="/search">
   {% if settings.search_option != "everything" %}
     <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product" />
   {% endif %}
   <input type="text" name="q" class="search_box" 
    placeholder="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" 
    value="{% if search and search.results.first.price %}{{ search.terms }}
   {% endif %}"/>
</form>
```

```
var input = $(this).find('input[name="q"]');

/* Part A: Change the width of the search input box to 600px when cursor was 
   click on the search box. When I comment out part B, 
   then the width will change to 600px. 
   If I does not comment out part B, the width does not change */

input.bind('click', function(){ 
   console.log("width changed");
   $(this ).css({'width' : '600px'});
});

/* Part B: When user click on any body element which is not the input box,
    change the width of the input box back to original length. 
    This code below does not work the way I want. When the cursor was placed 
    in the input box, it also executes this part of code,which is remain at its 
    original length */

$("body:not(.search_box)").bind('click', function(){ 
   $('input:text').css({'width' : 'inherit'}); 
});

/* Part B: I also tried code below, but does not return the result which I want */

$("body *:not(input:text)").bind('click', function(){ 
   $('input:text').css({'width' : 'inherit'}); 
});

/* hide the search result when click on input box and body*/
$('body').bind('click', function(){
   $('.search-results').hide();  
});
```

Comment: You can immediately see from the genial code highlighter used by StackOverflow that someting is really wrong. (Yes, the missing quotes.)

Comment: You opened double quotes like `$("body` but where have you closed them?

Comment: just updated. I copied wrongly.

Comment: I think, you use `focus` event instead of `click`

Comment: Thanks @SeokjunHong I will try it

Answer (score 2):

use `focus` and `blur` events:

```js
var input = $('input[name="q"]');

input.on("focus blur", function(evt) {
  $(this).css({width: evt.type=="focus" ? "400px" : "auto" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="q" type="text">
```

Animate? well... `.animate()` it than, a bit more difficult cause you need to store the initial size.

```js
var input = $('input[name="q"]');


input.on("focus blur", function(evt) {
  
  if($(this).is("animated")) return;    // Do nothing while animating

  var isFocus = evt.type=="focus";      // Detect event type
  if(isFocus) this.w = $(this).width(); // On focus remember the element initial Width
  $(this).animate({width: isFocus ? 400 : this.w }); // Finally
  
}).on("input", function() {
  
  $(this).trigger("blur");              // Trigger a blur if user selects a dropdown value
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><input name="q" type="text"></span>
```

### CSS only

Logically I would not write the above *"nonsense"* if it was possible to use CSS transition from an `"auto"` width to `400px` and back...

**But if you define a starting CSS width** than you can use CSS!

```css
input[name=q]{
  width:180px;     /* NEEDED */
  transition:0.3s; -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}
input[name=q]:focus{
  width:320px;
}
```

```html
<input name="q" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks @roko I will try it

Comment: @user21 your'e welcome. Try it! P.S: instead of `"auto"` you could use `"inherit"` or `"initial"` or whatever you want... you got the idea.

Comment: I have another problem.  While I am typing in the search box, the drop down list will appear. When I click on the item on the drop down list, ,The width of the search box has changed back to its original even though the drop down list didn't hide. Is there a way that I can change the width back to its original only after the drop down list has hide. Likewise, I doesn't want the width go back to its original length even though the drop down list has not appear.

Comment: Is there a way that can write animate for this function in one line too?

Comment: can I write if($('.search-results').is(":hidden")) in css? The code is like in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tangjeen/hmjgjec3/

Comment: @user21 I cannot see any input in your fiddle and I don't understand why would you use `:hidden`

Comment: because I would like to change the width back to original length only when the .search result is hidden

Comment: @user21 I don't know what you're trying to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use animation with `focus` / `blur` events 
https://jsfiddle.net/L84j4ykx/

```js
$('.inp').on('focus', function () {
  $(this).animate({
    width: '400px'
  }, 1000, function () {

    $(this).on('blur', function () {
      $(this).animate({
        width: '200px'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inp" type="search" name="q">
```

---

**Edit:** To prevent waiting while completing the animation in case of speed change , then you can use `stop()` before `animate()` for each event

```js
$('.inp').on('focus', function () {
  $(this).stop().animate({
    width: '400px'
  }, 1000, function () {
  
    $(this).on('blur', function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '200px'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inp" type="search" name="q">
```

Comment: Thanks @el.oz for your answer. I like the animation effect

Comment: When I put the width as 'inherit' or 'initial' when the input blur, it does not change back to its original width.

Comment: If you meant inheriting the width from the parent then cache parent width as a variable and use it, give a look to this fiddle jsfiddle.net/L84j4ykx/1